# Python: Interpolate lines and get the Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have the following problem. I have the coordinates of points of a line. Now I want to connect them or interpolate them, so that I have a continuous line in a room and calculate the Euclidean distance to the  rest of the box coordinates which could be for example a (21,41,91) shaped numpy array (that should not be the problem with scipy, skimage etc.).

So I want to do something like this but in 3D:

[Distance Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuMjk.png)

[Distances on grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9ph8.png)

So the the line voxel will get zeros and all the rest coordinates ones. I don't want distances of the points of a line or total lengths of the lines

Here is a visualization how the points are spread in the room

[Spread points in room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJ3q.png)

[image]

And here are coordinates in a numpy array of one line of them for example. They are ordered in the right order:

```
import numpy as np

line1 = np.array([[ 14,11,35],
 [ 13,14,37],
 [ 11,17,38],
 [ 11,19,41],
 [ 12,21,43],
 [ 15,24,46],
 [ 18,27,46],
 [ 19,30,45],
 [ 20,33,45],
 [ 21,36,46],
 [ 22,37,47],
 [ 24,37,47],
 [ 23,40,49],
 [ 24,42,51],
 [ 21,44,50],
 [ 19,46,48],
 [ 18,47,45]])
```

Comment: Interpolation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation. The euclidian distance part is more obscure. I assume you can get the mean point for each set of boxes and compute the distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [108]: from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

In [109]: fig = plt.figure()
     ...: ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


In [112]: ax.plot(line1[:, 0], line1[:, 1], line1[:, 2])
Out[112]: [<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D at 0x13913a20>]
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE:** saving it as a TIFF:

```
In [128]: from PIL import Image

In [129]: from io import BytesIO

In [130]: buf = BytesIO()

In [131]: fig = plt.figure()
     ...: ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
     ...:

In [132]: ax.plot(line1[:, 0], line1[:, 1], line1[:, 2])
Out[132]: [<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D at 0x14cdccc0>]

In [133]: fig.savefig(buf)

In [134]: Image.open(buf).save(r'd:/temp/out.tiff')
```

Comment: Nice, but is it also possible to get the coordinates of that interpolated line that fits in a specific grid with linspaces 1 in each dimension or to save that line in a 3D tiff?

Comment: Ok that is a picture of the matplotlib plot, but i ether need an arrray with all interpolated coordinates of the line or an 3d tiff with only the line in a back box